# Laravel Vue, javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

I decided to make some changes to a project I had previously attempted to deploy. As such, I had to make some changes in the env file, in order to be able to view the project locally.

When I did however, certain javascript segments don't seem to be working. 3 image sliders specifically, which worked fine before, now simply show all of the contents at once, and the buttons for moving the items do nothing.

The reason I think it's a broader js issue is that a minor vue component that I had made available globally via vite.config.js isn't showing up either. Vue specific javascript seems to be working without any issues.

As I'm not getting any errors anywhere, and I haven't made any (seemingly) relevant changes, I'm completely stumped as to what might be causing this.

My vite.config.js is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';
// import cors from "cors";
import fs from 'fs';


export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
        template: {
            compilerOptions: {
                isCustomElement: (tag) => ['Tags'].includes(tag),
            }
        },
    }),
    basicSsl(),
],
server: {
    // port: 3000,
    // https: true,
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
        // port: 3001,
        protocol: 'wss',
        origin: false,
    },
        key: fs.readFileSync(`C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key`),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(`C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt`),},
resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true,
    server: {
        https: true,
        origin: 'localhost'

    },
    cors: true,

},
});
```

And one of the sliders

```
<div id="slider">
                    <h1 class="font-bold font-ropa text-tra text-base text-transform: uppercase mt-6">You have also looked at</h1>
                    <div class="relative bottom-3">________</div>

                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide relative" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-indicators absolute right-0 bottom-0 left-0 flex justify-center p-0 mb-4">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                                data-bs-slide-to="0"
                                class="active"
                                aria-current="true"
                                aria-label="Slide 1"
                            ></button>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                                data-bs-slide-to="1"
                                aria-label="Slide 2"
                            ></button>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                                data-bs-slide-to="2"
                                aria-label="Slide 3"
                            ></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-inner relative w-full overflow-hidden font-ropa">
                            <div class="carousel-item active float-left w-full">
                                <div class="flex">
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/NOW1HC006P_N/NOW1HC006P_N-98x150h.jpg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/S2WTWS1/rn%20pulover-98x150h.jpeg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item float-left w-full">
                                <div class="flex">
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/WRUP4HC006/nCF704dQ-98x150h.jpeg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/WRUP4RC006/usnje-98x150h.jpeg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item float-left w-full">
                                <div class="flex">
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/WRUP4RC006/usnje-98x150h.jpeg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="w-1/2 h-40 flex">
                                        <img
                                            src="https://freddy.hr/image/cache/catalog/izdelki/CITYWALKLXCM_NV1/citywalklxcm_nv1_-_02M-98x150h.jpg"
                                            class="block"
                                            alt="Camera"
                                        />
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="text-sm text-black">WR.UP®, NORMALNI STRUK, SKINNY, CRNE</div>
                                            <span class="text-lg">127,05 EUR</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            class="carousel-control-prev absolute bottom-full text-black flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline right-16"
                            type="button"
                            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                            data-bs-slide="prev"
                        >
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="text-black">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button
                            class="carousel-control-next absolute bottom-full flex items-center justify-center p-0 text-center border-0 hover:outline-none hover:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:no-underline right-0"
                            type="button"
                            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                            data-bs-slide="next"
                        >
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon inline-block bg-no-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="text-black">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```